# How can I return a list of future dates based on a day (e.g. the dates for mondays until the years end)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a booking system and a user can book a time slot.

**The time slots are listed by day and time:**

```
Wednesday - 10am to 2pm

Wednesday - 3pm to 9pm

Sunday - 3pm - 7pm

Tuesday 12pm - 4pm
```

What I need to happen is return some future dates based on the chosen time slot. So for example if I was to choose the Sunday slot above, another select field would be populated with dates.

**The dates would be presented in a day and month format:**

```
5th June

8th May

30th September
```

The dates would be Sundays only or what ever day was chosen in the time slot drop down list.

I would also need some way to limit how many dates were returned. So maybe every Sunday up to 6 months in the future.

I've taken a look in the API and can't seem to find anything for this.

Would appreciate your help.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a list of upcoming days for a particular for the next 6 months, you can use something like this.

```
require 'date'

start_date = Date.today
end_date = 6.months.from_now
weekday = 0 # 0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday
dates = (start_date..end_date).to_a.select { |day| day.wday == weekday }
```

After that, you can format the days as you like

```
dates.map { |date| date.strftime("#{date.day.ordinalize} %B %Y") }
=> # 12th October 2014
   # 19th October 2014
   # 26th October 2014
   # ...
```

Comment: Nice and clean.  I suggest you add `require 'date'`, and possibly just make the range `(Date.today..6.months.from_now)`. You don't need `to_a`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sure but since this is in Rails, so shouldn't it be automatically required?

Comment: I didn't notice the Rails tag, but had I done so, it wouldn't have mattered, as I know nothing of Rails. :-) Sampriti, SO is only for grown-ups. Oh, I guess you are one.

Comment: I put this in a helper method. It's working great but how do I return a date in the format of 5th, June 2014? There isn't an example of how to prefix th, st, nd, rd in the API's.

Answer (score 0):

How about a method that takes an array argument of what days are selected and returns dates within a range and then format it to fit your needs.

```
def valid_date_range(days)
  days.map! {|day| day.to_date.wday}
  today = Date.today
  till_date = Date.today + 1.month
  valid_dates = (today..till_date).to_enum.select {|date| days.include?(date.wday)}
  valid_dates.map {|date| date.to_formatted_s(:short) }
end
```

So if you needed Monday and Friday you'd call date_range(["Monday", "Friday"]) and it would return an array:

```
[" 7 Oct", "13 Oct", "14 Oct", "20 Oct", "21 Oct", "27 Oct", "28 Oct", " 3 Nov", " 4 Nov"]
```

Or, you may just want to play with till_date to get just the current months days like "Date.today.end_of_month" and get:

```
 ["10 Oct", "13 Oct", "17 Oct", "20 Oct", "24 Oct", "27 Oct", "31 Oct"]
```

Comment: Can you modify this so I can pass in a day string e.g. "Friday"?

Comment: Yep. Added days.map! {|day| day.to_date.wday } to convert them to their relative integer. Just as a side, this method doesn't quite adhere to good SRP practices and could use some refactoring later on for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach than those solutions building ranges of dates, instead build a range of offsets and then build your dates.

```
start_date = Date.new(2014,10,15)
day_offsets = (0..180).find_all { |i| i % 7 == 0 }
dates = day_offsets.map { |d| (DateTime.now + d).to_date}
```